# Convert XMLGregorianCalendar to oracle timestamp value

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp

I need to convert XMLGregorianCalendar to Oracle Timestampformat

My database data type is of Timestamp format.

Trying to execute the query using Java.

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem by self?

Comment: Hard to understand your question, do you mean that you need in a **java** program to cast a `XMLGregorianCalendar` to a `Timestamp` so you can insert it to an oracle DB table ?

Comment: Yes,Exactly.Type casting from XMLGregorianCalendar to Timestamp

Answer (score 2):

By default the [`XMLGregorianCalendar#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toString%28%29) method returns the date string in [`ISO 8601`](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD", For example: "2014-12-10T12:49:28-08:00", with 'T' being a delimiter for Time. A shortcut hack would be to replace the 'T' with a space, but that is not the preferable option in my opinion.

Since you need the date string in a format that is compatible with Oracle's [`TO_TIMESTAMP()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_timestamp.php) function, something like this: "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3", you could convert it to a java.sql.Timestamp by passing in the milliseconds.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar now = new XMLGregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar calenderNow = now.toGregorianCalendar();
Timestamp createOnTimestamp = new Timestamp(calenderNow.getTimeInMillis()));
```

If you need to pass the timestamp to a prepared statement as a formatted String you could do this:

```
String createdOnString = createOnTimestamp.toString(); 
//returns yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

or if you have a specific format you want to use:

```
String createdOnString = new SimpleDateFormat("yourformat").format(createOnTimestamp);
```

*Note: you can see what Oracle's default timestamp format is by running the following query:

```
SELECT value FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT';
```